# GCP Spring boot migration 3.x : Required a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, migration, google-cloud-pubsub

I've a java 17 application with many modules. I've changed the spring boot version from 2.7.6 to 3.0.6 and I've got the following issues appearing on the module handling PubSubs from GCP

> Parameter 1 of method myMessageChannelAdapter in com.controller.file.MyController required a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate' that could not be found.

I've migrated the gcs dependencies as follow :

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
   ....
<!-- gcs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Here is how I'm creating my PubSubInboundChannelAdapter :

```
@Bean
public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter myMessageChannelAdapter(
        @Qualifier("myChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
        PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
   return getInboundAdapter(inputChannel, pubSubTemplate, subscriptionName);
}


@Bean
public MessageChannel myChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

Should I add another dependency to have a PubSubTemplate automatically autowired or should I create it ?
If I have to create it, I can't find a proper way to do it

Comment: Can you please share me the full class of PubSubInboundChannelAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.project-id properties and update to last spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies 4.5.1
I have solve my migration from springboot 2.7 to 3.1 with pubsub and I didn't created PubSubTemplate, it 's created by spring

Answer (score 1):

No need to add this config spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.project-id,

4.5.1 alone could fix the issue.